# how to filter and extract case class objects from big flat csv files using shapeless?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have a big flat denormalized csv file containing multiples objects on single row like this:

```
a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3 ...
...
```

and I have objects:

```
case class A(a1: Int, a2: String, a3: Float)
case class B...
...
```

and the legacy is writing complicated adapters for extracting each class. I recently read some talks about shapeless and I know I can solve this with generic programming with shapeless.

and there's even a csv parser example, perfect. my thoughts would be:

1. parse the csv into List[String]
2. filter the ListString with object field information
3. using the filtered ListString and fed it with the Csv Parser example
4. thus I can extract multiple objects a row from the csv file.

problems I have:

1. I am still on scala 2.10, I seem to have configured the compiler plugin correctly( egg. mvn clean install works properly).  but intellij fails to compile occasionally, throws exceptions.

   ```
   <groupId>org.scala-lang.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>macro-paradise_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   ```
2. this code is from `shapeless` example

   ```
   implicit def deriveHConsOption[V, T <: HList](
       implicit
       scv: Lazy[CSVConverter[V]],
       sct: Lazy[CSVConverter[T]]
     ):CSVConverter[Option[V] :: T] = new CSVConverter[Option[V] :: T] {
       override def from(s: String): Try[shapeless.::[Option[V], T]] = s.span(_ != ',')
   ```

however I'm having following compiler errors:

> Error:(70, 28) wrong number of type arguments for ::, should be 1
>   ):CSVConverter[Option[V] :: T] = new CSVConverter[Option[V] :: T] {
>                             ^

3. my attempts to filter the csv using shapeless:

   ```
   //code to filter and extract one object 
   def extractCSVColumnsAndParse[T]:
       val labl = LabelledGeneric[T]
       val keys = Keys[labl.Repr].apply
       val keyNames = keys.toList.map(_.name)
   ```

however it seems T could only be concrete Class Type

> Error:(86, 35) could not find implicit value for parameter lgen:
>   shapeless.LabelledGeneric[T]
>           val labl = LabelledGeneric[T]

Comment: For #2, you need to import `shapeless.::`, otherwise, it uses the list constructor, that only has one type parameter.

Comment: Could you give some context about where you're using your snippet from #3? Is it in a method you want to apply multiple time with concrete types?

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet right that solves #2. #3, I was hoping I could write one function but call it multiple times to parse different objects out.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about your IntelliJ problem, but I'll give the other two some answer:

- 2: `::` is `scala.collection.immutable.::` (the `List` constructor), unless you explicitly import `shapeless.::` (the `HList` constructor).
- 3: While you're dealing with generic types, you cannot assume anything on them. They might be `Int`, `Any`, `MyCaseClass`, `Nothing`, ... So the compiler cannot find a `LabelledGeneric` for them (indeed, what would be the `LabelledGeneric` for `Any`?). Therefore, you must explicitly tell all your generic methods that your type has an instance of `LabelledGeneric[T]`, and this is done by giving it as an implicit parameter (or a context bounds, which is the same thing, under the hood). So for instance, you could do

  ```
  // alternatively, def extractCSVColumnsAndParse[T: LabelledGeneric]
  def extractCSVColumnsAndParse[T](implicit ev: LabelledGeneric[T]) = {
    val labl = LabelledGeneric[T]
    val keys = Keys[labl.Repr].apply
    val keyNames = keys.toList.map(_.name)
    ...
  }
  ```

  And then, when you use it, for explicit case classes:

  ```
  extractCSVColumnsAndParse[MyCaseClass]  //no need to pass the parameter, it is already in scope
  ```

  The "magic" of shapeless is that it generates your `implicit ev: LabelledGeneric[MyCaseClass]` for you, but it can only do so for specific types (using macros), so you have to tell the compiler that it exists, if you're dealing with generic types.

**EDIT**

After that, you get an error with `val keys`, because the type parameter for `Keys` must be an `HList`, so you have to enforce this in some way, because `LabelledGeneric[T]#Repr` is not necessarily an `HList`. And, you also need to provide an implicit `Keys[Repr]`, for the same reason as with `LabelledGeneric`.

```
def extractCSVColumnsAndParse[T, Repr <: HList](labl: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, Repr], K: Keys[Repr]) {
  val keys = K()
  val keyNames = keys.toList.map(_.name)
  ...
}
```

However, this makes it less easy to call with a specific case class, since you cannot do `extractCSVColumnsAndParse[MyCaseClass]` anymore. This is because scala methods only have one list of type parameters, so you must give them all or none of them.

A convoluted way to avoid this is the following pattern, assuming your method will actually have some parameter (say, the `List[String]` from the csv file, or the csv file path):

```
def extractCSVColumnsAndParse[T] = new Extractor[T]

trait Extractor[T] {
  def apply[Repr <: HList](csv: List[String])(implicit labl: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, Repr], K: Keys[Repr]) = {
    ... // put the logic here
  }
}
```

Now you can call it using

```
extractCSVColumnsAndParse[MyCaseClass](csv)
```

This pattern allows you to specify only the first type parameter, the second one being inferred at compile time.

Comment: thanks for the help: now the error goes to the map line: Error:(88, 24) type arguments [labl.Repr] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [L <: shapeless.HList]
        val keys = Keys[labl.Repr].apply().toList.map(_.name)
                       ^

Comment: Sure, I should have taken a closer look before answering. I edited to solve that problem, and what followed.

Comment: both still didn't work yet: [ERROR] ExcelReader.scala:36: could not find implicit value for parameter toTraversableAux: shapeless.ops.hlist.ToTraversable.Aux[K.Out,List,Lub]
I still can't rule out my #1 problem yet. maybe I shall build using the shapeless csv example

Comment: I'd hoped you'd got the pattern by now :). any implicit that's missing must be given as parameter to your method. Here, you should do `def apply[Repr <: HList, Keys <: HList, Lub](implicit K: Keys.Aux[Repr, Keys], trav: ToTraversable.Aux[Keys, List, Lub]) = ...`